# Can this operator taking boundary conditions for the wave equation be extended to $L^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

We denote by $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ the collection smooth function in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which are compactly supported.

Fix $t>0$ and consider the linear operator $L:\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^3) \to \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ which maps $f\mapsto \partial_tu(\cdot, t)$ where $u$ is a solution to
$$
\begin{cases}
u_{tt} - \Delta u = 0\\
u(x, 0) = 0\\
u_t(x,0) = f.
\end{cases}
$$
For $p>1$, $p\neq 2$ (for $p=2$ the result is well known), can $L$ be extended to a map from $L^p(\mathbb{R}^3)\to L^p(\mathbb{R}^3)$?

I am not quite sure how to approach the problem, but I figured I should look for a sequence of funtions $(f_n)\subseteq \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ such that $\lVert f_n \rVert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^3)}$ is uniformly bounded but 
$$\lVert \partial_t u_n(\cdot, t)\rVert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^3)}\to\infty.$$
I'm not quite sure how to find such a sequence or if this is even the correct approach. Any input is appreciated!